# Xamarin Forms: Display error occurring in view model

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm following tutorials/examples for a Xamarin Forms project, where there is a view with a C# code-behind, binding to a view model.  However, I want to catch an exception occurring in the view model and display it in an alert or use any other common technique for displaying errors.

Here is the view, which reloads data using a refresh:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyCompany.App.Views.DashboardPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyCompany.App.ViewModels"
             xmlns:dashboard="clr-namespace:MyCompany.App.ViewModels.Dashboard;assembly=MyCompany.App"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    
    ...

    <RefreshView x:DataType="dashboard:DashboardViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        ... content
    </RefreshView>

</ContentPage>
```

Then I have the C# code behind for the XAML:

```
public partial class DashboardPage : ContentPage
{
    DashboardViewModel _viewModel;

    public DashboardPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new DashboardViewModel();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _viewModel.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

And finally the view model where the loading happens. It inherits from the BaseViewModel which is provided in the tutorials.

```
public class DashboardViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private DashboardItemViewModel _selectedItem;
    public ObservableCollection<DashboardItemViewModel> Items { get; }
    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; }
    public Command<DashboardItemViewModel> ItemTapped { get; }

    public DashboardViewModel()
    {
        Title = "Dashboard";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<DashboardItemViewModel>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());
        ItemTapped = new Command<DashboardItemViewModel>(OnItemSelected);
    }

    async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Items.Clear();

            var items = await GetItems();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    private static async Task<List<DashboardItemViewModel>> GetItems()
    {
        // Where errors happen

        return items;
    }

    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        SelectedItem = null;
    }

    public DashboardItemViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
            OnItemSelected(value);
        }
    }

    async void OnItemSelected(DashboardItemViewModel item)
    {
        if (item == null || item.Uri.IsNotSet())
            return;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(item.Uri);
    }
}
```

I can't see any overridable methods in ContentPage for catching exceptions. What's the best way to catch an exception and display it in an alert?

Comment: you can create an Error property on your VM and bind it to a Label or other UI

Comment: @Jason The advantage of that approach is that the label stays visible, unlike the alert, where information is lost once you close it. Also you can style a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, but for catching errors I use try/catch method.

```
try
{
  //your code here
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
  await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Warning", "Error: " + exc, "Ok");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a convenient way to access the alert from anywhere.  I didn't know the view model could interact with the UI like that.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer helpful